# HipperlinkField Dentro de Datagrid No redirige asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp

Estoy intentando añadir series de un articulo para que este sea trasladado a otra bodega

la funcionalidad consiste en que al dar clic en el control de hipperlink los registros a los cuales se les pretende añadir serie, este se redirija a una pagina, en la cual se debe hacer dicho proceso

para lograr lo anterior intentó hacer lo siguiente

```
   <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText = "Añadir Serie" DataTextField = "Id_traslado_detalle" DataNavigateUrlFields = "Id_traslado_detalle" SortExpression = "Id_traslado_detalle" DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "~/aspx/Inventario/DetalleTrasladoSerie.aspx?id={0} "/>
```

mi gran inconveniente es que no se ejecuta ninguna accion al dar clic, péro si se muestra el dato y aparece el control como link

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intentaste copiar la dirección `URL` del enlace para ver a donde apunta?

Comment: si, en definitiva me redirige a la pagina que requiero

Comment: Si copiaste la dirección `URL` y te llevo a la página que quieres no veo problemas en el control. El error debe estar en otra parte, para encontrarlo debes hacer un `debug` coloca un `breakpoint` en el `Page_Load()`.

Comment: @victor estoy haciendo el proceso directamente desde la pagina asp, desde un datagridview mas no desde codebehind

Comment: Lo digo para que descartes que algún proceso interno de la aplicación te impida redirigir tu página. Porque no veo ningún problema en la manera en que construiste el control.